# Polaroid 250 and 125- help with testing operation

Tags: polaroid

I purchased two Polaroid land cameras (250 & 125)at estate sales, cleaned them up and put in fresh batteries to test. Neither "did anything" after I put in the batteries. I'm not sure what to do to "test" them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "did anything". The only thing the battery does is provide power to the meter/shutter circuit during exposure. Have you tried putting film in one of them, pulling the black card, cocking the shutter, and firing off a shot yet?